# ¿Como Mostar datos obtenidos de un object en angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs

Acabo de hacer una consulta a mi base de datos la cual me retorno `object`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos los guarde en localstorage

`localStorage.setItem("Tickets", JSON.stringify(response));`

y en otra función los llamo así:

```
var headshot = localStorage.getItem("Tickets");
```

Sucede que tengo una variable repo:

```
      var repos = [
    {
      'rut'      :  '...here..',
      'numero'       : '...here...',

    }
```

y quiero llenarla con los datos obtenidos para después mostrarlos en un buscador con ng-repeat...

¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Me estoy enredando, Aquí tengo el código html ya que estoy usando Angular-material:

implemente el segundo ejemplo:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

gracias a los que me estan ayudando!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como más arriba tambien te aconsejo que no utilices `JSON.stringify`

No es necesario que crees una variable repos.
Para buscar dentro de tu lista ng-repeat puedes ocupar "filter" de AngularJS (Angular 1), es muy sencillo. Te dejo el codigo

```
$scope.tickets = localStorage.getItem('Tickets');
```

En el html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="ingrese rut" ng-model="buscar">
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | filter : buscar">
     {{ticket.rut}}
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/GjdXaq)

Comment: angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: donde utilizas toLowerCase?

Comment: eso me sale en consola :o

Comment: te deje un codepen con el codigo

Comment: quieres tambien buscar dentro de la lista ng-repeat?

Comment: estoy usando un autocompletar por angularjs-material, es el segundo que aparece en la pagina mmm gracias.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46657/discussion-between-sioesi-and-hernan-humana).

Answer (score 1):

¿Es necesario que guardes en LS y después obtengas desde LS cada vez que haces una llamada al backend?. Sería conveniente usar la función de éxito en la cadena de promesas del servicio/factory llenes primero la variable con los datos y después guardes en LocalStorage (te recomiendo ngStorage). Después asignas esa variable a tu $scope correspondiente para mostrar los datos en el ngRepeat. OJO! Que el "buscador" (filtro) del ngRepeat es muy ineficiente, prueba con otras alternativas como ngTable. Saludos.

Comment: resulta que implemente un buscador de angular-material, por eso la necesidad de llenar los datos en la variable repos

Comment: Sí perfecto, entiendo, la implementación del buscador es otra cosa. La asignación de los datos a la variable es otra.

Comment: En ese caso la respuesta de @sioesi debiera ser suficiente al asignar los datos a una variable de tu $scope. Debes pasar ese array al buscador/tabla de ngMaterial

Answer (score 1):

Como dice pablo alejandro, tienes que hacer un `JSON.parse`, o en AngularJS (Angular 1) un `angular.fromJson()`, asignarlo a tu variable y ahí si pasarlo a tu variable, pero OJO si usas `md-autocomplete` (supongo que ese estas usando) debes poner `md-no-cache="true"` para que puedas cargar cambios en caso de que la lista sea dinámica.

`md-autocomplete` usa un `md-virtual-repeat` el cual mejora notablemente la impresión de muchas filas. (Uso `angular-material` en varios proyectos)

Comment: amigo tengo una duda me puedes ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

el `JSON.stringify(response)` está convirtiendo el objeto json obtenido a un string, para leerlo con ng-repeat tienes que pasarlo de nuevo a json object, puedes convertirlo con `json_response_object = JSON.parse(string_response);` y luego el característico `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in json_response_object">
  <span>{{obj.numero}}</span>
  ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar directamente los datos de la respuesta:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cosa in datos">
      Rut: {{cosa.rut}} numero{{cosa.numero}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat